# Stop C# proceeding to server side script upon dropdown list javascript validation failure

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

I am trying to validate the current value of a dropdown list and check if it has one of the options selected upon a button click. If not, my goal is for a JS prompt to appear asking 
the user to select something. My dropdown code looks like this:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="TBDrop" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataValueField="id" Width="155px">
        <asp:ListItem Text="---Select---" Value="0" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="YES" Value="1" />   
        <asp:ListItem Text="NO" Value="2" />   

        </asp:DropDownList>
```

My js script is:

```
        function validate_dropdown1() {
            var dropdown = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentMasterID_TBDrop');
            if (dropdown.selectedIndex == 0) {
                alert("Please select from list");
                return false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentMasterID_tagComplete').onclick("tagComplete_Click");
                return true;
            }
        }
```

My button is like this:

```
  <asp:Button ID="tagComplete" runat="server" Height="23px" OnClick="tagComplete_Click"  Text="Complete" OnClientClick="validate_dropdown1();" />
```

My issue is that upon no selection, the js prompt appears but still proceeds on the onclick tag event (OnClick="tagComplete_Click") which I aim not to. I have tried, as you can see above to
use

```
            } else {
                document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentMasterID_tagComplete').onclick("tagComplete_Click");
                return true;
            }
```

but this results to an Out of Memory error prompt. How should I use JS validation so that if the user selects something on the dropdown aside the default text, it will proceed on the server side script, otherwise stay as is on the current page

Comment: You could also use a (custom) validator to validate server side before  proceeding with the rest of the request. JS validation is no real validation.

Comment: @Bartdude what do you mean? I would like to do it via JS so that the page will not need to load and checking is done in an instant

Comment: You can include the client script in .NET validation if you wish. But you could aswell do as you intended in the first pace and intercept button action in javascript, stopping anything if validation fails. Problem is that js-validation only is no real validation cause it can be bypassed. But that's maybe not an issue in your case.

Comment: Yeah, if JS is disabled on browser would be 1 option to bypass it. But in my case JS disabling is not applicable. But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small change to your button declaration.

```
OnClientClick="return validate_dropdown1();"

<asp:Button ID="tagComplete" runat="server" Height="23px" OnClick="tagComplete_Click"  Text="Complete" OnClientClick="return validate_dropdown1();" />
```

If validate_dropdown1() return false then the event will not be raised and the server will not post back.

Comment: that did it. I was trying to actually use this when my JS script lies on an external file but this method didn't work. Perhaps I didn't write the correct format to include JS on ASP.NET